# Assistance in understanding what is being asked barycentric formula

Tags: polynomial-approximations

i) Recall the general barycentric formula that computes the weights assuming unequally-spaced nodes (although we will be considering equally-spaced nodes, we will use the general formula to avoid taking factorials of very large numbers). Taking 0=−1 and =0+ℎ,=0,⋯,, with ℎ=[1−(−1)], implement a routine that generates the barycentric weights. This routine should have a handle of the form
function [weights]= equally_spaced(n, xnodes)
where xnodes is the set {} and weights is {}. Test this routine with n=10, printing out the 11 weights.
I am totally lost. Not sure what is being asked